# Showing Toolbar Title based on HTML title?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to set set the Title for toolbar in material design. In normal case, I know I can use `mActionBarToolbar.setTitle`. However, what I have is a `WebView` which will open different webpages. Is it possible for me to set the Title for toolbar which will change automatically according to the `<title></title>` section in the HTML page?

I tried to use the below code, but the Title become empty.

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [`WebView.getTitle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getTitle()) method to obtain title of the current page

Also to automatically change the title, you can use [`WebViewClient.onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, java.lang.String url)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String))

set like this:

```
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
    {  
        mActionToolbar.setTitle(view.getTitle()); 
    }  
});
```